# doctrine $entityManager->getRepository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I'm newer with php and doctrine. I'm trying to create a small project and I have a problem when I try a findAll method. No errors are showed when I executed it.

This is my Canales.php class (in `/src/model/dto` folder)

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Canales
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Canales")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Canales
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Nombre", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="URL", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $imagen;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Ingles", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ingles;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->nombre = null;
        $this->url = null;
        $this->imagen = null;
        $this->ingles = null;
        $this->id = null;
    }

    /**
     * Class Constructor
     * @param    $nombre   
     * @param    $url   
     * @param    $imagen   
     * @param    $ingles   
     * @param    $id   
     */
    public function __construct($nombre, $url, $imagen, $ingles, $id)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
        $this->ingles = $ingles;
        $this->id = $id;
    }



    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Canales
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Canales
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set imagen
     *
     * @param string $imagen
     * @return Canales
     */
    public function setImagen($imagen)
    {
        $this->imagen = $imagen;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imagen
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImagen()
    {
        return $this->imagen;
    }

    /**
     * Set ingles
     *
     * @param boolean $ingles
     * @return Canales
     */
    public function setIngles($ingles)
    {
        $this->ingles = $ingles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ingles
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIngles()
    {
        return $this->ingles;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

My composer.json

```
    {
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

my DaoGenerico class

```
    require_once("bootstrap.php");
    function showAction(){
    $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Canales');
    echo "..";
    $productos = $repository->findAll();
    echo "OK";
    if (!$productos) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }
    else{
        var_dump($productos);
    }
}
```

and my prueba.php

```
<?php
include('./src/model/dao/daoGenerico.php');

showAction();
?>
```

As I said before, when I execute the method `showAction` in `daoGenerico.php`, no errors are showed but I think that the problem is in using `getRepository('Canales')` method, maybe Doctrine doesn't find Canales because the next line `echo ".."` never is showed;

Any advice or idea? how could I show the errors?

thanks in advance

EDIT.

I paste the bootstrap.php too

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
//$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'yoga',
    'charset'  => 'UTF8',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Comment: You missed to pass `$entityManager` on your function. And please also provide `bootstrap.php` code here

Comment: I have found the error. The line require_once("bootstrap.php"); should be inside of showAction method because now, $entityManager is unavailable. Now, the error is "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class 'model/dao/Canales' does not exist' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php". How should it be? getRepository('./model/dao/Canales') ? Canales.php is in folder /src/model/dto/Canales.php. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add `namespace model/dao;` in  your `Canales.php`

Comment: Thanks for your message, Dolly Aswin. Now this error is not showed. I have to change model/dao for model\dao. I have another error but this can be resolved :)

Comment: So, the current problem has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, the main problem is resolved. I have another error "Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "model\dto\Canales" is not a valid entity or mapped super class." and I still trying to resolved it. Thanks for your help, Dolly

Comment: Dolly Aswin, could you post your comment as an answer? I would like to accept it and add a vote for you...

Comment: Done. Thanks @barthuin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to pass `$entityManager` on your function.

And please add namespace `model/dao;` in your `Canales.php`